# RSYNC only Updated Files

Tags: rsync, ubuntu-12.04

I am running the following script to push information off of a remote server and store it on a local server. The script works but every time it is ran it downloads everything over again. I have tried running it in a pull scenario where the destination runs the script and pulls the info from remote server. Its still wanting to download everything. I have also included the option --update and again same thing.

I run this same script on another set of servers and it on those servers it only pulls updated files.

In short how can I modify this script to update only new files? Is there something on the servers itself I am missing?

```
rsync -avz --delete -e ssh user@1.2.3.4:/source/storage/location/ /destination/storage/location/
```

Comment: What filesystems are in play here? (On both the source and destination)

Comment: The source is ext4 and the destination is NTFS. I never really considered that to be part of the problem. I am using NTFS on the destination because the drive is an external hard drive. In the event something happens to my destination computer I can easily connect it to a Windows machine to recover the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTFS does not have the granularity in it's timestamps for rsync to be able to compare properly.

You need to either compare using checksums instead of timestamps (`-c`) or add the `--modify-window=1` argument.

Comment: So your suggesting I use the following line: rsync -acvz --delete -e ssh user@1.2.3.4:/source/storage/location/ /destination/storage/location/ . Also I did reformat the NTFS disk to ext4 and it did work.

Comment: Yes, adding the -c option will work, but will be more intensive to calculate. Using ext4 (or other 'native' Linux file system would be better if you can.

Comment: Agreed. I went ahead and chanced it to ext4. But its still nice to know why it wasnt working and how to make it work.